# context.output behaviour in tie with Windowing

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying understand behaviour of context.output method in Apache Beam

I saw that based on [javadoc](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.2.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/DoFn.WindowedContext.html#output-OutputT-) each message will be promoted to the next step with **timestamp of negative infinity**

I know that pub/sub will automatically populate publishTime based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49221667/does-pubsub-auto-generate-timestamps) and based on [docs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#element-timestamps) from Apache Beam each element in a PCollection has an associated intrinsic timestamp that will be equal to publishTime as I understand.

Does it mean that context.output will overwrite publishTime by **timestamp of negative infinity** for the next step? And according to [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#windowing) about windows all messages will be in the same window in terms of usage of session window?

Comment: What you said is correct, but your final result will be dependent on triggers, so it often comes down to accumulation/triggering. You should be able to use [outputWithTimestamp]( https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/DoFn.WindowedContext.html#outputWithTimestamp-OutputT-org.joda.time.Instant- ) if you want more control of the timestamp.

Comment: @BrunoVolpato
Am I right that in such case that I described in the post window session will act as a global window on unbounded collection because of all elements will have timestamp of negative infinity and purpose of triggers is to fire panes only, right?
And usage of withAllowedLateness is useless because infinity + 1 minute (for example) == infinity?